# Fancy indexing in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am basically trying to do something like this but without the for-loop... I tried with `np.put_along_axis` but it requires `times` to be of dimension 10 (same as last index of `src`).

```py
import numpy as np

src = np.zeros((5,5,10), dtype=np.float64)

ix = np.array([4, 0, 0])
iy = np.array([1, 3, 4])

times = np.array([1 ,2, 4])
values = np.array([25., 10., -65.])

for i, time in enumerate(times):
    src[ix, iy, time] += values[i]
```

Comment: Do you want the `values` to appear in `src` or you really want to add them to whatever is already in `src`? Using `zeros` for `src` causes the output to be identical whether you use ` src[ix, iy, time] += values[i]` or `src[ix, iy, time] = values[i]` inside your loop.

Comment: I want to add them :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to use [`np.add.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html), preparing the indices first (as below):

```
r = len(values)
indices = (np.tile(ix, r), np.tile(iy,  r), np.repeat(times, r))
np.add.at(src, indices, np.repeat(values, r))
print(src)
```

**Output**

```
[[[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  25.  10.   0. -65.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  25.  10.   0. -65.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.  25.  10.   0. -65.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]]
```